# how to pass data from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to asp.net MVC5 and i am trying to pass data from view to controller as a string.
Here is controller class:

```
namespace Movies.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // GET: HelloWorld

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult welcome(FormCollection fc, string reportName)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = reportName;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Index View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MVC Movies";
}
<h2>My Movies List</h2>

<p>Hellow from our view template</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome", "HelloWorld", FormMethod.Get))
{

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="reportName" />
        <input type="submit" />

    </p>
}
```

Here is welcome view:

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>welcome</h2>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
}
<ul>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        <li>@ViewBag.Message</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Actually my Index method is passing a view that will have a textbox for string in it in a form and then on clicking submit button application should pass that string in the Welcome method in the same controller. On clicking submit button browser is showing a windows that resources con't be found.

Whats the problem..? thank you for your time..:)

Answer (score 2):

1) The action name is case sensitive, you are using "Welcome" in the form definition , but the action must has the name "welcome" with **w** lower case.

2) Your form is doing a GET but you are specting a POST in the action

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult welcome(FormCollection fc, string reportName)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = reportName;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: you are right fals as my mistake was i was using get insted of ost in my beginform. but how it can be httpget there as i am posting data on clicking submit button. httppost will work when user post data from view to controller.. here what will be the benefit of httpget..?

Comment: @MudasirRao If you are using GET form, data will not be submitted in the request body but rather as query string parameters appended to request URL. In your case, request would look like /HelloWorld/Welcome?reportName=somename

Comment: I can also do this thing like this...@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Movies",FormMethod.Get))

Answer (score 1):

Replace `FormMethod.Get` with `FormMethod.Post` in your beginform.

Answer (score 1):

Modify FormMethod.Get to FormMethod.Post:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Welcome", "HelloWorld", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="reportName" />
        <input type="submit" />

    </p>
}
```

Change your action implementation to this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult welcome(FormCollection fc)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = fc["reportName"];
        return View();
    }
```

However, I'd strongly suggest that you create a view model for your form and use it instead of FormCollection.

Comment: Barisa thank you for your answer.. i figured it out... can you explain me the benefit of view model over form collection..?

Comment: With view model, you don't have to take out values from FormCollection manually - model binder does that for you in the background as long as the name of the property in your view model matches name of the input field on the form. Also, you can annotate properties on your view model with data annotations and get validation (check RequiredAttribute i.e.).

Comment: Barisa you mean to say that i can directly have values from view(V) to model(M) and then i can save them in data base...?

Comment: But i was passing value to controller to just render another view. In this scenario i cant involve Model. m i right..?